# Keep checking connection if available in Node and clear setTimeout

Tags: javascript, node.js

In node i keep checking if connection is available if it is it will get token and store in variable but if not then catch error will be thrown and it will then execute `setTimeout` to try again in 2 seconds.

But i think i need a clean way to clear the `setTimeout` because when i log it i keep getting higher number in `Symbol(asyncId)` this to me feels like it keeps adding `setTimeout` more and more to memory?

```
export const getToken = async () => {
  try {
    if (!GLOBAL_VARS.authToken) {
      await auth(`Getting token`)
    }

    // Do more stuff
  } catch (error: any) {
    tokenTimeout()
  }
}

getToken()
```

```
export const tokenTimeout = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    getToken()
  }, 2000)
}
```

Comment: `setTimeout` only executes its callback once after the specified delay has expired. On the other hand, `setInterval` executes the callback repeatedly at the end of each specified interval.

The value returned by `setInterval` can be passed into `clearInterval` to stop the execution loop.

Comment: Yep maybe setInterval is better for this case

Comment: setInterval is probably not any better. My guess is the memory gain has nothing to do with timeout or interval. You also are not awaiting calls so you really have a design flaw in your code.

Comment: what do you mean not awaiting calls? i am awaiting auth

Comment: Some exception logging in that `catch` scope would probably be a good place to start.

Comment: Yeah, but your recursion is not. Your original call is not.

Answer (score 0):

Yest it will add more setTimeouts to the memory.

you can clear it like this:

```
export const tokenTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
    getToken()
  }, 2000)


export const getToken = async () => {
  try {
    if (!GLOBAL_VARS.authToken) {
      await auth(`Getting token`)
    }

    // Do more stuff
  } catch (error: any) {
    const timeout = tokenTimeout()
  }
}

getToken()

/// use it wherever you want 
clearTimeout(timeout);
```

Comment: And that is a error since timeout is in a different scope. And I am not sure how clearing it would fix memory issues.

Comment: I've changed my code, I'm not sure if these changes will make a difference but try it.

Answer (score 0):

Memory is going to increase because of whatever you are doing with `auth()` and not because you are creating timeouts.

The issue I see with your code is not really using async await properly. It should look more like

```js
const sleep = (ms) => 
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });

export const getToken = async (count = 0) => {
  try {
    if (!GLOBAL_VARS.authToken) {
      await auth(`Getting token`);
    }
  } catch (error: any) {
    await sleep(2000);
    if (count < 10) await getToken(++count);
    else throw new Error('Taking too long to get auth token');
  }
}

(async function () {
  await getToken();
})();
```

Comment: i'm just not sure if i need to wrap with IIFE and async at the top level of app.ts i just need that to start the function once

Comment: Well do you want to use async?

Comment: I do inside getToken i just dont't understand why wrap in IIFE with async just leave it like so getToken() for the initial run i don't have anything else that need running

Comment: Also this does not solve the timeout keep adding more memory, i've just run and i see my ram keeps increasing

Comment: Also in auth i'm just trowing error nothing more is being done but still getting memory increase on each timeout

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the correct stats for memory?

Comment: i have Activity Monitor open and see 3 node instanced running and one of them keeps increasing memory